# Is there a way to start an Azure Virtual Machine when someone try to access it through its DNS name?

Tags: azure

For context, we have an Azure Virtual Machine that we use to test our app before pushing the changes to production. This VM automatically shutdown every evening to save some energy. Is there a way to make it start when trying to access its DNS name (******.cloudapp.azure.com)? It would be better than starting it at a fixed time every morning but if it is impossible or too complicated, is there a way to make it start at a specified time?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/start-stop-vms/overview

Answer (score 1):

Starting the vm using events requires some changes in your architecture.

You can start a vm at fixed time using automation accounts. Look at this tutorial on Microsoft learn to accomplish your goal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management-config

Answer (score 1):

If you had a firewall in front off your VM you could log the HTTP 404 events, then trigger a function that started your VM.

But it is not trivial and the firewall would add extra cost (it may be more expensive than your VM)

So the best way is probably just to start the VM at a fixed time.

If you need the VM permanently you could look into Reserved instances to save costs. It could save you upto 80% https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/reserved-vm-instances/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I made a mistake. Actually, our VM is already reserved, we only shut it down for energy/environmental purposes. I like the firewall idea but as you said it is probably too expensive and time-consuming.